# Interprete $e_jAe_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is from Artin Algebra:

> With matrix $A$ arbitrary, determine product $e_jAe_k$. Here $e_i$ is column vector with single nonzero entry $1$ in position $i$.

I don't know how to compute this or even dimensions match.

Comment: What are you stuck on? Just write out the product for $A = (A_{ij})$.

Comment: @anomaly Suppose $e_j,e_k$ are of dimension $1\times m$ and $A$ is $m\times m$, how is this product defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should probably read $e_j^T A e_k$ or $e_j' A e_k$, and $A$ needs to be a square matrix. Writing the indices as superscripts, the result of this multiplication is

$$
\sum_m \sum_n e_j^m A^{m,n} e_k^n
$$

but observe that the only non-zero term is the one with $e_j^j$ and $e_k^k$; these elements are equal to 1. Therefore the answer is just $A^{j,k}$.